# How to interrogate Typing parameters (List, Tuple, Dict...)

Tags: python, type-hinting, introspection

I'm looking for a way to recursively traverse the schema of both `NamedTuple` and `@dataclass` type definitions.  I'm doing this without example objects, just interrogating the types themselves.

My code works for simple cases such as:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple


class Child(NamedTuple):
    foo: int

class Parent(NamedTuple):
    child: Child
```

If given the class `Parent` (not an object of it) my code will automatically discover the class `Child`.  What I can't get working is cases such as:

```py
from typing import NamedTuple, List


class Child(NamedTuple):
    foo: int

class Parent(NamedTuple):
    child: List[Child]
```

My problem is simply this: I haven't yet found a way to iterate over the parameters of a `typing.List` and likewise have the same problem for other types like `Tuple`, `Dict`...

It feels like this should be possible and even trivial.

Answer (score 1):

*way to iterate over the parameters of a `typing.List`*

After bit of experiments I found that `__args__` attribute might be useful for you, consider following example:

```
import typing
intlist = typing.List[int]
print(intlist.__args__)
```

output

```
(<class 'int'>,)
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid using private methods if at all avoidable.  They are usually subject to change without warning.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this in the documentation... The typing library has useful public methods `get_args()` and `get_origin()`.

Describe here in the manual: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args

For example:

```py
import typing

for arg in typing.get_args(typing.Tuple[int, str])
    print(arg)
```

Results in:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```